# Facebook doesn't show thumbnails from a shared link

Tags: html, facebook, metadata, thumbnails, meta-tags

When I post a link on Facebook, the images on inside the page are never loaded. I am using Facebook meta tags:

```
<meta content='...' property='og:title'>
<meta content='...' property='og:description'>
<meta content='url to image' property='og:image'>
```

Also, I've tried to set up image tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url to image">
```

But neither one way doesn't work, images are not loaded. I am trying it a few days, but nothing has changed.
Title and description of the page are successfully loaded.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> #### Updating Objects
>
> When an action is published, or a Like button pointing to the object
> clicked, Facebook will 'scrape' the HTML page of the object and read
> the meta tags. The object scrape also occurs when:
>
> - The object URL is input in the Object Debugger
> - **Every 7 days** after the first scrape
> - When an app triggers a scrape using an API endpoint
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/

If you neither put the URL in the [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), nor used an app to work with your link yet, you might have to wait 7 days.

You can try to:

- check the object properties on `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=HTTP://YOURSITE.COM`,
- or see its scraped version on :
  `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=HTTP://YOURSITE.COM`.

In both cases, check whether the `og:image` displays correctly. If yes, you just re-generated the scrape of your page, so it might work a bit later! Else, is there an error?

Also make sure to respect the exact notation (we never know):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851565_496755187057665_544240989_n.jpg" />
```

Note the little  `/>` at the end.